# How to solve "Could not resolve GitHub"?

Tags: github

When ever I try pushing my project to another branch I always receive this error "Could not resolve GitHub" what is the solution to this?

Comment: Hey! How are you using Github? Are you pushing through the desktop application, Sourcetree, terminal, ...?

Comment: Does it literally say "Could not resolve GitHub"? That would be weird, as GitHub isn't a URL. Please copy and paste the _exact_ error message, and the command you're using to generate it.